# Basic Rake Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I am implementing a very basic rake task:

filename lib/tasks/dosbis.rake

```
namespace :app do

desc "My first rake file"

    task :dosbis => :environment do

    end

end
```

When I execute using the following command I receive these errors:

```
MacBook-Air-de-JCR:tasks jcr$ sudo bundle exec rake dosbis --trace
Password:
(in /Users/jcr/web/net/dos_prod)
/Users/jcr/web/net/dos_prod/lib/tasks/dosbis.rake:1: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/jcr/web/net/dos_prod/lib/tasks/dosbis.rake:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
... task :dosbis => :environment do
...                               ^
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:641:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:641:in `each'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:641:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:244:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:446:in `load_tasks'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/jcr/web/net/dos_prod/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
MacBook-Air-de-JCR:tasks jcr$
```

I really appreciate your help.
Thank you

This is my system information and version of rails and ruby............

```
MacBook-Air-de-JCR:tasks jcr$ ls -l dosbis.rake
-rw-r--r--  1 jcr  staff  139 20 jul 22:06 dosbis.rake
MacBook-Air-de-JCR:tasks jcr$ pwd
/Users/jcr/web/net/dos_prod/lib/tasks
MacBook-Air-de-JCR:tasks jcr$ 
MacBook-Air-de-JCR:tasks jcr$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.4
MacBook-Air-de-JCR:tasks jcr$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

Comment: is `desc "My first rake file"` unindented in your original code?

Comment: hi mus, yes is with unindented

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the invisible character `\r` where it's not supposed to be. The warning message

> encountered \r in middle of line

suggests this.

Try to enable your editor to show invisible characters as well to see the undesired character.

Answer (score 0):

`desc` must be on the same level as `task`

```
namespace :app do

    desc "My first rake file"

    task :dosbis => :environment do

    end

end
```